# Flicker while animating UIView alpha

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview

I have two views that I'm switching between, the problem is that when I switch from view1 to view2, the background color of view2 appears first then all its subviews appear, which causes unwanted flicker.

The problem is here:-

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"blabla" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:5];
view1.alpha = 1;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

view1 background color is shown first then its subviews are shown after about 0.3 seconds, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following code before the animation block:

```
[view1 setNeedsLayout];
[view1 layoutIfNeeded];
// Now all the subviews of view1 are in place
[UIView beginAnimations:@"blabla" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:5];
view1.alpha = 1;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```